# input-value does not update in react-component, text does though

Tags: reactjs

I have the common problem, that parts of my component do not get updated, although I call forceUpdate(). All other proposed solutions that I found here on SO did not fix my problem:

```
 <meter value={getLevel()} max="1" value="0">{getLevel()}</meter>
```

The text within the meter-tag gets updated, but the value remains the same. This most probably is a duplicate, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have 2 value attributes, is it normal ?

Comment: Dude, you are right. I am gonna delete this question, I am too embarresed. it was a long day.. Thanks man!!

Comment: I spent 2 hours on this...

Comment: classic dev life :-D